# Troubles with SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations

Tags: c++, openssl, key, ssl-certificate, server

I have openssl server and I need not to allow connection for all clients. I found this function for this `int SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(SSL_CTX *ctx, const char *CAfile,const char *CApath);`. It works fine with one CAfile with one certificate, but I need add one more, so I tried to add certificate to this file like this:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

but the program just read the first and doesn't read the second. Next, I tried with CApath, I renamed my .crt files to `hash`.0 and now program doesn't read them. What am I doing wrong?

Certificates in .crt format.

Works fine: `SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx, "keys/c1.crt", NULL);`

Doesn't work: `SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx, NULL, "keys/hashes");`

Both lines of code returns 1.

Comment: If several CA certificates matching the name, key identifier, and serial number condition are available, only the first one will be examined. This may lead to unexpected results if the same CA certificate is available with different expiration dates. If a "certificate expired" verification error occurs, no other certificate will be searched.

Comment: @VladimirKunschikov, different extensions (03502257.0 and 03502257.1), different serial number and still doesn't work

Comment: You can reproduce error on test certificates?

Comment: @VladimirKunschikov, what are u talking about? Certificates are correct and server works fine wit both of them, when only one in use.

Comment: So you can generate file with two test certificates and reproduce an error?

Comment: @VladimirKunschikov, I have 2 different certificates c1.crt and c2.crt, how can I make a single file with both of them except the example above?

Comment: cat 1.crt 2.crt  >12.pem

Comment: the point is to generate test certificates to be sure that your code is working; then examine differencies between test certificate and your non-working ones.

Comment: @VladimirKunschikov, I'm working now with test certificates and it's not working. I made a single .pem file with my certificates and it's not working.

Comment: What does sk_X509_OBJECT_num(_pCTX->cert_store->objs) returns for your loaded file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the `CApath` argument, I think you need to use OpenSSL's [`rehash`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/c_rehash.html) (or `c_rehash`) utility.  Say you have your certs in the `keys/` directory, like so:

```
keys/c1.crt
keys/c2.crt
```

Then you use `openssl rehash` to generate the links/names that OpenSSL expects:

```
$ openssl rehash keys
```

Which prepares that `keys/` directory for use in `SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations()`:

```
SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(NULL, "keys");
```

Hope this helps!